# Prevent recursive function running setTimeout from compounding

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, browser, settimeout

I wrote a Chip-8 emmulator in JavaScript [(source)](https://github.com/taniarascia/chip8) and made a playable browser version [here](https://taniarascia.github.io/chip8/).

It contains an HTML select:

```js
<select>
  <option value="PONG">PONG</option>
  <option value="TETRIS">TETRIS</option>
</select>
```

Which loads a ROM from a file every time one is selected:

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', event => {
  const rom = event.target.value
  loadRom(rom)
})
```

This `loadRom` function fetches the ROM, converts it to a useful form, and loads it into an instance of a CPU class. The `cpu` has a fetch-decode-execute cycle that gets called with `step()`.  I created this `cycle` (main) function to call itself in a setTimeout.

```js
const loadRom = async rom => {
  const response = await fetch(`./roms/${rom}`)
  const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
  const uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  const romBuffer = new RomBuffer(uint8View)

  cpu.interface.clearDisplay()
  cpu.load(romBuffer)

  let timer = 0
  async function cycle() {
    timer++
    if (timer % 5 === 0) {
      cpu.tick()
      timer = 0
    }

    await cpu.step()

    setTimeout(cycle, 3)
  }

  cycle()
}
```

This works fine, until I load a new ROM with the select. Now the cycle is compounded, and the game goes twice as fast. Every time you load a new ROM, it compounds again and creates a new cycle.

How can I create an infinite loop, but stop it and start a brand new one without compounding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, have the current timeout to be a persistent variable, and then call `clearTimeout` with it right before calling `loadRom`. If nothing has been loaded yet, the `clearTimeout` just won't do anything.

But because you have `await`s as well, you'll need to check whether a new rom gets loaded while the `await`s are going on. One way to accomplish this would be to have another persistent variable, the current `romBuffer` being used - if it's not the same as the `romBuffer` in the function closure, then another rom has started, so return immediately (and don't recursively create a timeout).

```
let timeout;
let currentRomBuffer;
const loadRom = async rom => {
  const response = await fetch(`./roms/${rom}`)
  const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
  const uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  const romBuffer = new RomBuffer(uint8View)
  currentRomBuffer = romBuffer;
  cpu.interface.clearDisplay()
  cpu.load(romBuffer)

  let timer = 0
  async function cycle() {
    timer++
    if (timer % 5 === 0) {
      cpu.tick()
      timer = 0
    }
    await cpu.step();
    if (romBuffer !== currentRomBuffer) {
      return;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(cycle, 3);
  }
  cycle()
};
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed that it was that easy and I didn't think of it. Thank you! I'll accept the answer once it lets me.

Comment: Scratch that, it appears to work, but if the cycle is stuck in a Promise before changing, the speed increase will continue to happen.

Comment: Oh, good point - you can keep track of the current `romBuffer` instead, and if it changes during an `await`, don't call the `setTimeout`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue, but the issue turned out to be outside of the scope of my question (I need to cancel a running promise), so I'll accept this because it's correct for the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `setInerval` and keep track of the handle.

Then clear it when loading the new (or the same) rom.

```
const loadRom = async rom => {
    const response = await fetch(`./roms/${rom}`)
    const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
    const uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    const romBuffer = new RomBuffer(uint8View)

    cpu.interface.clearDisplay()
    cpu.load(romBuffer)

    // if rom is loaded, clear it!
    if(this.lastLoad)
        clearInterval(this.lastLoad);

    let timer = 0
    async function cycle() {
        timer++
        if (timer % 5 === 0) cpu.tick()

        await cpu.step()
    }

    // keep track the handle.
    this.lastLoad = setInterval(cycle, 3);
}
```